# What does running an application as admin entail?

Tags: windows-10, permissions, compatibility, uac

When we run an application as admin, what does that really mean? We know it has rights to make changes to the system but rights to exactly what?

The one thing that stands out is the registry which it has full access to but what else a typical application may need rights to that is not there as a regular user?

I could see program files or windows system folders as well but my guess is that most applications probably don't need to make any changes there (in other words it would run without elevated access to it).

So I am trying to identify components of running an *application as admin* so I can hopefully apply these changes manually one by one if that's possible. I am doing this because my application needs admin rights to run properly on windows 10 and I want to narrow it down what exactly it needs that access to.

Comment: A "typical application" does not need rights to anything more than the session items of the user running it. An installer, in order to install to be visible to all potential users, would require those admin rights to write to the locations all users have access to.

Comment: See this article....https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/identity-protection/user-account-control/how-user-account-control-works

Answer (score 2):

What exactly an application needs admin rights for varies by application, but you have identified the two most common issues of running without elevated rights: protected areas of the file system and registry.

To solve your exact issue, you should run Process Monitor (from SysInternals). Then run the application, without elevation. ProcMon will tell you what the application is trying to do and failing. Look for Access Denied results.

Comment: This answer is good but it won’t work, if the reason the application needs to be elevated, is because of file, folder, or registry permissions.   Changing the default permissions of a system key or a folder like Program Files is worse idea then running an application as an Administrator

Comment: It's typically not Program Files, but rather the application's folder in Program Files. Changing the permissions on such a folder is much safer than admin rights.

Comment: Microsoft best practices disagree.  An application’s data should be contained within AppData, changing the permissions to Program Files, can allow broken installers (for example) to remove everything within the folder because of a wildcard character in a delete step in the script if the permissions are changed.

Comment: Yes of course, but you don't always have control over what an app does, especially if your company didn't make it.

Comment: I ran process monitor but don't see any access denied in results or even in details column. I see some "NAME NOT FOUND" and  "FILE LOCKED WITH ONLY READERS" but the rest is all "SUCCESS".

Answer (score 1):

Running an app as as admin generally allows it to do anything up to and including formatting your hard drive.  Well written apps, other than utilities such as installers, should not need that.

That said, Microsoft provides a tool by the name of [LUA Buglight](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/aaron_margosis/2015/06/30/lua-buglight-2-3-with-support-for-windows-8-1-and-windows-10/) which you can use to work with poorly written apps to provide them with minimal fixes instead of giving them free rein.

Aaron Margosis' blog is in general an excellent place to learn about these sorts of fixes.

Looks like the download link at the moment is [here](https://msdnshared.blob.core.windows.net/media/MSDNBlogsFS/prod.evol.blogs.msdn.com/CommunityServer.Components.PostAttachments/00/10/62/49/95/LuaBuglight.zip).